# Ajax calendar not displaying correctly at first time in .net?

Tags: asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AJAXToolKit calendar in visual studio. I can't find the styles. Please look at the image, when the page loads, when i click the calendar icon, the extender does not have any styles.

After i selected some date, the styles are working properly.

So, Basically the styles are working if it has value.

### Without Value:

[image: if it has no value]

### With Value:

[image: If it has value]

### aspx code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="IncidentDate_edit_lbl" runat="server" Text="Date: " CssClass="labelstyle"></asp:Label>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IncidentDate_edit_tbx" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CssClass="blueLabelStyle" Text='<%#Bind("Incident_Date")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="IncidentDate_edit_ibtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar-icon.png" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="incidentdate_edit_calendarextend" runat="server" TargetControlID="IncidentDate_edit_tbx" EnabledOnClient="true" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" 
                                            PopupButtonID="IncidentDate_edit_ibtn">
    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" ValidationGroup="Incident"
                                            ValidationExpression="\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}" Display="None" ControlToValidate="IncidentDate_edit_tbx">                                                                        
                                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator1">
    </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>                                    
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can't immediately think of what could be causing this to happen, but a possible solution is to have a default value loaded, perhaps the current date? Also is this in all browsers or is it just happening in one?

Comment: to isolate the problem, remove the validators let's see what you got.

Comment: @JOEW Thanks. But its happening to all the browsers. :-(

Comment: @jomsk1e Thanks. I checked and removed the validators as well. But still i got the same thing. :-(

Comment: Do you know where can i overwrite the styles for the AJAXcalendar?

Comment: please see my answer below.

Comment: Since you said it works with values, can't you just assign a default value to the field? (say, today's date?)

Comment: Have you tried to make sure the js is being put in there after all of your other js files?

Comment: The Date is not an mandatory field. So it might be null. Thanks

Comment: @deadlychambers Thanks. Which js did you mention?

Comment: I would try to make sure that ajaxtoolkit is loaded after the other ones (Assume Jquery, maybe someothers).  Then make sure other js is not being loaded at the bottom of the page.  That can cause some issues as well.

Comment: @deadlychambers Can you tell me how can i set the today's date to the field for the new action?

Comment: I would try $("#incidentdate_edit_calendarextend).val("01-01-2014") or maybe $("#incidentdate_edit_calendarextend).attr("value","01-01-2014") but I also am not sure what that calendarExtender turns into after the js has ran... I would try to inspect everything that has been added to the dom after the js has ran.  Maybe try to find the input that you can load the value into. Is this calendar using moment?

Comment: @deadlychambers Thanks and yes it is working at the moment. Is it any other way, I mean on the aspx page to set the today's date to that text field. Because when I tried `text = System.DateTime.Now` giving the Today's date with Time as well. I just want to insert today's date and change from '/' to '-' in between dates.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a CSS problem, try this in the header of your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ajax__calendar_container { z-index : 1000; }
</style>
```

If value 1000 doesn't work, try 5000.

If that doesn't work try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ajax__calendar {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px !important;
        top: 0px !important;
        visibility: visible; display: block;
    }
    .ajax__calendar iframe
    {
        left: 0px !important;
        top: 0px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check the complete style

```
    <style type="text/css">
     .ajax__calendar_container {
        padding: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: default;
        width: 170px;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: tahoma,verdana,helvetica;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_body {
        height: 139px;
        width: 170px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_days, .ajax__calendar_months, .ajax__calendar_years {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 139px;
        width: 170px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_container TABLE {
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_header {
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_prev {
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        float: left;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-image: url(WebResource.axd?d=vuxhVfo1YLyjqq0iGRXgQLQX43rVnAr0061zfFv0yrJptA2vlKQIjqV6bQH7kcz62NSlNo4XlKkgaWR89p2wWS0-_eYynob71_2kyJ_BbCehN90iBwIVlHvOujE4LEMnC_XgRxhDLUgjt5q6z-RyhBJEqA0I88WHStYXd8XDskQ1&t=633885366380000000);
    }

    .ajax__calendar_next {
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        float: right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-image: url(WebResource.axd?d=1vEP8Pv3XMqD6PfaIev5s6qGIqSFwx2eI9GjFosFKgLLJo8GkIOA59ujgqiG0gCg8XxgaPKCBQazTqQPIxNumjgdpN7yZMBP2ZzOnYX70AkEhvKWlRzNTNKTKL36xKq8nFeBI-IuZ7k4FJoWSKj4oxp2Bnx546ji6VGnO1TwPsM1&t=633885366380000000);
    }

    .ajax__calendar_title {
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_footer {
        height: 15px;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_today {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-top: 3px;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_dayname {
        height: 17px;
        width: 17px;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0 2px;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_day {
        height: 17px;
        width: 18px;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_month {
        height: 44px;
        width: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .ajax__calendar_year {
        height: 44px;
        width: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_container {
        border: 1px solid #646464;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_footer {
        border-top: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_dayname {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_day {
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_month {
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_year {
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_day {
        background-color: #edf9ff;
        border-color: #0066cc;
        color: #0066cc;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_month {
        background-color: #edf9ff;
        border-color: #0066cc;
        color: #0066cc;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_year {
        background-color: #edf9ff;
        border-color: #0066cc;
        color: #0066cc;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_other .ajax__calendar_day {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #ffffff;
        color: #646464;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_other .ajax__calendar_year {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #ffffff;
        color: #646464;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_day {
        background-color: #edf9ff;
        border-color: #daf2fc;
        color: #0066cc;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_month {
        background-color: #edf9ff;
        border-color: #daf2fc;
        color: #0066cc;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_year {
        background-color: #edf9ff;
        border-color: #daf2fc;
        color: #0066cc;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_title {
        color: #0066cc;
    }

    .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_today {
        color: #0066cc;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a setting in your Web.config

add the following to the bottom of your web.config

```
<ajaxControlToolkit useStaticResources="true" renderStyleLinks="true" /></configuration>
```